# Sending multiple parameters to WinJS.Binding.converter() function

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Is there a way to send more than one parameter to a `WinJS.Binding.converter()` function? Consider the following data and output:

```
        { contactName: "Tara Miller",  mainNumber: "555-405-6190", alternateNumber: "555-209-1927" },
        { contactName: "Bryan Bond",                               alternateNumber: "555-574-4270" },
        { contactName: "Jenna Siever", mainNumber: "555-843-8823", alternateNumber: "555-799-5424" },
```

[image]

Here is the HTML. The `MyData.chooseBestNumber` converter function is used to display either a person's main phone number or the words "no main number" if they don't have a main number:

```
<div id="listViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="contactCard">
        <div data-win-bind="innerText: contactName"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText: mainNumber MyData.chooseBestNumber"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS defining the converter function:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyData", {
    chooseBestNumber: WinJS.Binding.converter(function (mainNumber) {
        if (mainNumber) return mainNumber;
        else return "no main number";
    }),
});
```

Below is what I'd ultimately like to be able to do...passing more than one parameter into the converter function so that I can return either the main number (if it is defined), the alternate number (as a fallback), or a message (if all else fails):

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyData", {
    chooseBestNumber: WinJS.Binding.converter(function (mainNumber, alternateNumber) {
        if (mainNumber) return mainNumber;
        else if (alternateNumber) return alternateNumber; 
        else return "no phone numbers";
    }),
});
```

Is it possible to send more than one parameter to a `WinJS.Binding.converter()` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually bind your phone number div to the `this` keyword which will effectively bind the `innerText` property of that div to the entire model object. That way in your converter, you'd have access to the whole model.

So your updated code would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="listViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="contactCard">
        <div data-win-bind="innerText: contactName"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText: this MyData.chooseBestNumber"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Converter**

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyData", {
    chooseBestNumber: WinJS.Binding.converter(function (model) {
        if (model && model.mainNumber) return mainNumber;
        else if (model && model.alternateNumber) return alternateNumber;
        else return "no main number";
    }),
});
```