# WinJS, data-win-bind for script controlled binding?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

I'm working on a Windows 8 App in HTML5/Javascript. I created a custom control that uses a stack of DIVs to display content, and each DIV is rendered using `WinJS.Binding.Template`. The setup is close to the answer in this question: [WinJS.UI.ListView customize list item content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659952/winjs-ui-listview-customize-list-item-content) .

The binding data is close to:

```
[
    {
        "title": "title name",
        "allow_action": false
        "action_type": "go"
    },
    ...
]
```

And my template is close to:

```
<div id="entry" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div data-win-bind="textContent: title">
    </div>
    <a class="action">Action</a>
</div>
```

Upon binding, I would like to:

1. Change the `className` of `a.action` based on the value of `allow_action` and `action_type`.
2. Attach an event (`addEventListener`) to `a.action` upon binding, based on the contents of the binding data. This includes `allow_action`, `action_type` and other values.

Basically, I wish to have a pre-binding or post-binding callback function, with the element, and bind data as arguments. This doesn't appear to be possible with converters because converter doesn't let you access other fields.

Meanwhile I'm manually processing these things with DOM after `render`. I'm wondering if there are better options available. Thank you.

**Update**

As suggested by @GotDibbs and @RSW in the comments, I managed to solve problem #1 using the solution from [Sending multiple parameters to WinJS.Binding.converter() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713927/sending-multiple-parameters-to-winjs-binding-converter-function/14715804#14715804) . I'm wondering if #2 is still possible?

Comment: If you bind something to `this` instead of specific property, you can access your entire model from the converter. Also, there is no pre-bind or post-bind callback function that I'm aware of short of the promise returned from WinJS.Binding.processAll(). You may need to look into having the CSS class name and the event handler right on the object you're binding.

Comment: Could you give me an example on such converter?

Comment: He gives an example of binding to 'this' here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14715804/1309005

Comment: @RSW, thank you very much. I managed to get the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713927/sending-multiple-parameters-to-winjs-binding-converter-function/14715804#14715804 working in my own project.

Comment: I'm not at a computer that is capable of trying this out, but can't you setup a binding for the event you want to handle, bind it to your model with `this` again, and use a converter to redirect it to the actual handler you want to use?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the classname based on the properties of the object? Or are you saying you want to programmatically find out when the value changes? There are 3 solutions, but understanding what you wan to achieve will help get the right answer

Comment: I solved question #1 using @GotDibbs method. And what I'm looking for is to attach event to elements during the binding process (i.e. `render`). Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you're looking for by binding the event and className property on the desired element to your model, just like with the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713927/sending-multiple-parameters-to-winjs-binding-converter-function/14715804#14715804) mentioned in the comments. Therefore assuming you want to bind the click event, your anchor tag would look more like this:

```
...
<a data-win-bind="className: this Converters.getItemClassName; onclick: this Converters.getItemClickHandler">Action</a>
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I could bind onclick too. This is certainly an elegant solution.